# Is it possible to use a spring boot application for controlling a website and as an api at the same time?

Tags: json, spring-boot, api, rest, vs-web-site-project

So I have build a spring boot application which I use to run my website which contains of different html files), if I enter a certain url. But I also want it to be an api and to return json data, when given another url. Is that possible or do I have to implement two different applications for that?

Comment: Sure, it is possible but you have to decide how you want to develop and provide your HTML pages : static files, spring mvc, javascript framemorks as React, Vue, Angular ...

Comment: What you're describing is MVC (model-view-controller). This is one of the use-cases for Spring. https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/